# Why is head.data = 0 when head.next == null?

Tags: java, linked-list

Working on a HW assignment. The assignment is to reverse a linked list recursively. I just don't understand why at my `System.out.println(head.data)` line `head.data` always prints as `0`. Assuming I enter `4,5,6` (the fill and read methods for this work, if I put a print in my final else it will show that head is still 4, 5, 6) and `head.next` is `null`, doesn't that mean that `head.data` is equal to `6`? I know I've got a lot of other problems going on with trying to reverse this, but I just don't understand why when `head.next` is `null` the `head.data` is 0. I thought `head.next` was the next item in the list, not the current one.

```
public static Node reverse(Node head)
{
    Node n = new Node();
    if (head == null)
    {
        return n;
    } else if (head.next == null)
    {
        System.out.println(head.data);
        n.data = head.data;
        head.next = null;
        n.next = reverse(head.next);
        return n;
    } else
    {
        reverse(head.next);
        return n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
Node n = new Node();
if(head == null) {
    return n;
}
```

results in the reverse of an empty list being a single-element list with the default value of `data` (presumably zero?)

Also, the final `else` is clearly not right, as it never does anything to `n` before returning it.